# Acumatica change Shipping Terms on Sales Order creation

Tags: acumatica

I'm using Acumatica's contract based API to create sales order from an ASP.net application.  I need to update the "Shipping Terms" field under the "Shipping Settings" tab on a Sales Order when I create it (see below), but I can not find the property to use on the ASP.net objects that are provided through the contract based API.  How would I accomplish this?

[image]

Here is my current code for how I create the sales order:

```
using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient(binding, address))
{
    //Sales order data
    string customerID = "CUST1234;
    string orderDescription = "Automated Order";
    string customerOrder = "TEST";

    var orderDetails = new List<SalesOrderDetail>();

    foreach(var lineItem in order.line_items)
    {
        orderDetails.Add(new SalesOrderDetail {
            InventoryID = new StringValue { Value = lineItem.sku },
            Quantity = new DecimalValue { Value = lineItem.quantity },
            UnitPrice = new DecimalValue { Value = Decimal.Parse(lineItem.price) }, //TODO this should only be done for MHR owned sites
            UOM = new StringValue { Value = "EACH" },

        });
    }


    //Specify the values of a new sales order
    SalesOrder orderToBeCreated = new SalesOrder
    {
        OrderType = new StringValue { Value = "SO" },
        CustomerID = new StringValue { Value = customerID },
        Description = new StringValue { Value = orderDescription },
        CustomerOrder = new StringValue { Value = customerOrder },
        ExternalReference = new StringValue { Value = order.order_number.ToString() },
        Details = orderDetails.ToArray<SalesOrderDetail>(),
        ShippingAddressOverride = new BooleanValue { Value = true },
        ShippingContactOverride = new BooleanValue { Value = true },
        ShippingContact = new Contact()
        {
            DisplayName = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.first_name + " " + order.shipping_address.last_name },
            FirstName = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.first_name },
            LastName = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.last_name },
            Address = new Address()
            {
                AddressLine1 = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.address_1 },
                AddressLine2 = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.address_2 },
                City = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.city },
                State = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.state },
                Country = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.country },
                PostalCode = new StringValue { Value = order.shipping_address.postcode }
            }
        },

    };

    client.Login(_acumaticaUid, _acumaticaPwd, _acumaticaCompany, null, null);

    //Create a sales order with the specified values
    try
    {
        SalesOrder newOrder = (SalesOrder)await client.PutAsync(orderToBeCreated);

        client.Logout();

        return newOrder;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //order addition to Acumatica failed, update the order status in Woo Commerce
        client.Logout();
        Console.WriteLine("Acumatica could not add specified entity: " + e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on PatrickChen's comment, I created a new web service endpoint in Acumatica "SalesOrderCustom", where I used all of the default fields and then added "ShippingTerms" to the list as well. I then imported that web service into my .net project (with some headache due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42682402/5481661) issue) and was able to use the service to GET the sales order I wanted to add shipping terms to, and try to update it.  The code executes ok, but after the PUT operation is done, the object is NOT updated in Acumatica and the ShippingTerms property is returned as NULL.  What am I doing wrong? Code below:

```
public async Task<SalesOrderCustom> UpdateShippingTerms(string customerOrder, string originStore, string shippingSpeed)
{
    var binding = CreateNewBinding(true, 655360000, 655360000);

    var address = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AcumaticaCustomUrl"]);

    var soToBeFound = new SalesOrderCustom()
    {
        OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
        CustomerOrder = new StringSearch { Value = customerOrder }
    };

    using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient(binding, address))
    {
        client.Login(_acumaticaUid, _acumaticaPwd, _acumaticaCompany, null, null);

        try
        {
            var soToBeUpdated = (SalesOrderCustom) await client.GetAsync(soToBeFound);

            soToBeUpdated.ShippingTerms = new StringValue { Value = "USPS 1 CLS" };

            var updatedOrder = (SalesOrderCustom)await client.PutAsync(soToBeUpdated);
            //ShippingTerms is still NULL on returned object even after updating the object!!! WHY???

            client.Logout();
            return updatedOrder;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            client.Logout();
            Console.WriteLine("Acumatica could not find specified entity: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the default endpoint?  I had to create a new one to populate Shipping Terms.

Comment: @PatrickChen Yes I am using the default endpoint.  How did you create the new one?

Comment: @PatrickChen, I have created a new endpoint.  This seems to be the solution for version's below version 6 (I'm using 5.30).  I've found that after version 6 you can simply extend the endpoint.  If you want to post your answer, I will accept it

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting Acumatica 6, it's possible to update any field, not included into the ***Default*** endpoint. This feature is only available for endpoints implementing system contract of the 2nd version:

[image]

Below is the sample showing how to change **Shipping Terms** for a Sales Order with the ***Default*** Contract-Based endpoint by working with the `CustomFields` collection:

```
using (var client = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
    client.Login("admin", "123", null, null, null);
    try
    {
        var order = new SalesOrder()
        {
            OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
            OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = "SO003729" }
        };
        order = client.Get(order) as SalesOrder;
        order.CustomFields = new CustomField[]
        {
            new CustomStringField
            {
                fieldName = "ShipTermsID",
                viewName = "CurrentDocument",
                Value = new StringValue { Value = "FLATRATE2" }
            }
        };
        client.Put(order);
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Logout();
    }
}
```

No issues also noticed on my end when updating Sales Order **Shipping Terms** with the extended ***Default*** Contract-Based endpoint on a brand new Acumatica ERP 6.1 instance:

```
using (var client = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
    client.Login("admin", "123", null, null, null);
    try
    {
        var order = new SalesOrder()
        {
            OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
            OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = "SO003729" }
        };
        order = client.Get(order) as SalesOrder;
        order.ShippingTerms = new StringValue { Value = "FLATRATE1" };
        client.Put(order);
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Logout();
    }
}
```

For reference, adding screenshot of my extended ***Default*** endpoint used to update **Shipping Terms** in the **SalesOrder** entity:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much!  I know the version I'm using is not the most current, but I feel like the documentation [here](http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/I210-Contract-Based-Web-Services-5.3.pdf) on page 26 about custom fields, should mention that this can be used with non-custom fields like "ShippingTerms".  It is only used in the context of "customizations" and custom fields so I didn't think it was an option for my scenario.

Comment: I've tried using the same custom fields method for the "Salutation" field (SalesOrder -> Shipping Settings -> Attention field) because it also doesn't exist on the standard Contact object, however it does not work.  Do I need to do something differently in this case?

Comment: I've added a question for my comment above [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769288/acumatica-customfields-not-working-on-sales-order-create)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to add Shipping Terms when I created a new 6.0 endpoint.  The default endpoint that ships with Acumatica is not extendable.

Comment: Did you ever get it working before version 6.0?  I created the new endpoint with shipping terms added and I am updating shipping terms by first getting the sales order object, then updating it, then putting it (like the documentation says), but it does not update the field in Acumatica.  No errors either.

Comment: I haven't built a web service to consume this particular endpoint.

Comment: I updated my answer above to show how my web service uses the endpoint, which may be helpful.  However, it's still not updating ShippingTerms.  Any suggestions?